# Android : Is it possible to register a service to run after device reboot?

Tags: java, android, service

Is it possible to register a service like alarm service (that gives alarm at scheduled time) to run after device reboot? If possible, how to achieve it? A programmatical explanation help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

add in your manifest file:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.AlarmReloader">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

then do a class like that:

```
public class AlarmReloader extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    }
}
```

then you can reload your alarm, or launch a service.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/) from 2009 shows how you would achieve this.

You would have to create a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that listens for intents at startup. You also need to add this to your manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name="MyStartupIntentReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```